# Reading status updates of Facebook user requires read_mailbox permissions on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am porting an old iOS app (I was using the `ACAccount` classes from the iOS 6 framework, which became quite problematic so I'm switching to Facebook iOS SDK) that used to work properly before. I haven't touched the app in months, and it used to work before I started working on it again. I am making a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?fields=message&limit=200` which should normally return the text content of last 200 updates of the current user. It used to.

[image: code]

Now, I'm getting this:

[image: err]

I've double checked that the URL in the `connection` object is the same URL within the completion block, that should return the statuses (`FacebookSelfStatusesURL` is a hardcoded constant string anyway). The access token has the correct permissions, including the `user_status` permission that is needed to read the status updates. Reading user statuses have nothing to do with reading mailbox, which is obviously not a permission that I'd be asking for.

Am I missing something obvious, or is it a SDK bug (I've installed the latest, v3.7.1, as of September 13, 2013)? If this is a bug, are there any workarounds until it is fixed?

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: Show us a code when you authorize user and asking for permissions

Comment: just realized the problem now. nothing to do with auth. posting now.

Comment: I think you're just not asking for extended permissions (read_mailbox):  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: nope, i didn't need that anyway. added the answer. facebook acted a bit weird though for telling me that i needed that permission.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem:

I was using absolute paths with the `SLRequest`, such as `https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?fields=message&limit=200` which was fine with iOS Social Framework. But Facebook SDK requires relative paths, so changing the path to a relative path by stripping out the `graph.facebook.com` base worked. My "URL" is now `/me/statuses?fields=message&limit=200` and it works. Those URLs could be handled in a better way though, instead of telling an error message that has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve.

Anyway, if you are on Facebook SDK, be careful to use relative graph paths, not absolute URLs.

Comment: That's strange - error says exactly that you don't have read_mailbox permission, so it looked like you are not doing [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions. But if that worked for you, glad we could help :P

Comment: my best guess is that, because it was expecting a relative URL, maybe it messed up and because of the word 'message' in the URL, it parsed the URL internally to decide that I was trying to access the user's mailbox somehow, and complained about not having that permission. it definitely needs to check for the correct URL format, and correct it (or at least, raise an error about format not being correct instead of an obscure permission error).